# Oracle returns datetime format according by browser culture

Tags: c#, oracle, datetime, globalization, culture

Oracle returns datetime format according by browser culture that used by client.For instance while retrieving month on sysdate in oracle, if my browser culture is en-US return January, if tr-TR is return Ocak but i want to appear it only Turkish.I applied a couple changes on my code as follow but i am getting error some cases.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Ocak", "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture).ToString("MMMM", new CultureInfo("tr-TR"));
```

I can get error according by above sample.Because CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture and browser culture don't be same.January in not equal each Turkish month value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check your [`CurrentUICulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is  [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (based on `en-US`) or not like;

```
if(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture == CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
     var month = DateTime.ParseExact("January", "MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
     Console.WriteLine(month.ToString("MMMM", new CultureInfo("tr-TR"))); //ocak
}
else if(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture == new CultureInfo("tr-TR"))
{
     var month = DateTime.ParseExact("Ocak", "MMMM", new CultureInfo("tr-TR"));
     Console.WriteLine(month); //ocak
}
else
{
     //
}
```

Comment: thanks im going to try inside a few minutes.Your solution seems right.

Answer (score 0):

Add globalization tag in web.config

```
<globalization uiCulture="es" culture="es-MX" />
```

[Read more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx)

Comment: Hi gokul thanks for reply.i tried this tag in web.config file but it did not work.For this case, i want to change value when retrieving database.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<globalization />` tag in Web.config. Check this [LINK](http://www.big.info/2013/01/datetime-format-problem-with-turkish.html), this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
TO_CHAR (sysdate, 'Month', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = TURKISH')
```

You can use this code inside sql